# how to set aws node and vagrant node when the master node in the local

Tags: kubernetes

the kubernetes 1.2 support muti-node acrossing multiple service providers , now the master node running in my laptop , I want to add two work node respectively in amazon and vagrant . how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

> the kubernetes 1.2 support muti-node acrossing multiple service providers

Where did you see this? It isn't actually true. In 1.2 we added support for nodes across multiple availability zones within the same region on the same service provider (e.g. us-central1-a and us-central1-b in the us-central1 region in GCP). But there is no support for running nodes across regions in the same service provider much less spanning a cluster across service providers.

> now the master node running in my laptop , I want to add two work node respectively in amazon and vagrant

The worker nodes must be able to connect directly to the master node. I wouldn't suggest exposing your laptop to the internet directly so that it can be reached from an Amazon data center, but would instead advise you to run the master node in the cloud.

Also note that if you are running nodes in the same cluster across multiple environments (AWS, GCP, Vagrant, bare metal, etc) then you are going to have a difficult time getting networking configured properly so that all pods can reach each other.